# Limit image upload to one and disable audio, video and other document file types to upload

Tags: uploads

Somebody knows some trick in Add new Post to:

1. Disable the upload of audio, video and other filetypes.
2. Only accept the upload of an image (jpg, png, gif).
3. Limit the upload of each Post to only One image (no more than one).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can also [modify the Flash uploader to allow only one file](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15264/media-upload-choose-only-one-file/15631#15631). This works together with the solution Mike gave.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I was about to give up thinking that it wasn't possible or at least easy and then I stumbled onto the `wp_handle_upload_prefilter` filter which gives you exactly what you asked for! Here's the code:

```
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'yoursite_wp_handle_upload_prefilter');
function yoursite_wp_handle_upload_prefilter($file) {
  // This bit is for the flash uploader
  if ($file['type']=='application/octet-stream' && isset($file['tmp_name'])) {
    $file_size = getimagesize($file['tmp_name']);
    if (isset($file_size['error']) && $file_size['error']!=0) {
      $file['error'] = "Unexpected Error: {$file_size['error']}";
      return $file;
    } else {
      $file['type'] = $file_size['mime'];
    }
  }
  list($category,$type) = explode('/',$file['type']);
  if ('image'!=$category || !in_array($type,array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'))) {
    $file['error'] = "Sorry, you can only upload a .GIF, a .JPG, or a .PNG image file.";
  } else if ($post_id = (isset($_REQUEST['post_id']) ? $_REQUEST['post_id'] : false)) {
    if (count(get_posts("post_type=attachment&post_parent={$post_id}"))>0)
      $file['error'] = "Sorry, you cannot upload more than one (1) image.";
  }
  return $file;
}
```

And here are some screenshots showing how it looks in action:

[image: Screenshot of WordPress Upload Dialog with code to disable multiple uploads of anything besides image files]

[image: Screenshot of WordPress Upload Dialog with code to disable multiple image uploads per post]

Comment: Thanks Mike. Seems to work on non flash upload process, but using flash version shows: ... Sorry, you can only upload a .GIF, a .JPG, or a .PNG image file.

Comment: @José Pablo Orozco Marín - Thank you for finding my error. I think I've found the problem and posted a newer version of the code that I do believe works for the flash uploader now. Let me know!

Comment: @José Pablo Orozco Marín - Awesome. Glad I could help.

Comment: where should I add this line - and is it compatible tu wp 3.01 and latter ?

Comment: It is possible to limit by post type?

Comment: @José Pablo Orozco Marín - Sure, you have the `$post_id` so you can use `get_post()` to load it and test it's `post_type` property.

Comment: @Mike How to limit it to 10 images?

Comment: hey mike. This answer is quite old. Is there a better approach considering new version of wordpress?

Comment: It works cool with 3.5.1 buuut, for example, how can I apply this filter only when custom post_type is 'product'? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $post_id = isset($_REQUEST['post_id']) ? $_REQUEST['post_id'] : false;
 
 $post_type = get_post_type( $post_id );

Comment: It seems not to work (2016).

Comment: @it works but the error shows after upload complete, not when you select / drop file.