# Restrict file uploads by extension?

Tags: uploads, media-library, tinymce, visual-editor

Is there a way in WordPress 3.1 to restrict allowed file uploads by extension (images only) and file size?

Bonus question: Can I limit users to only be able view files they have uploaded themselves?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you can add a filter to `upload_mimes` to restrict to certain types.
The hook: http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/upload_mimes

The filter:

```
add_filter('upload_mimes','restict_mime'); 

function restict_mime($mimes) { 
    $mimes = array( 
                'jpg|jpeg|jpe' => 'image/jpeg', 
                'gif' => 'image/gif', 
                'png' => 'image/png', 
    ); 
    return $mimes;
}
```

From what I understand this will not work for admins or any user with the `unfiltered_upload` 
capability.
Also have a look at this post [Limit image upload to one and disable audio, video and other document file types to upload](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8107/limit-image-upload-to-one-and-disable-audio-video-and-other-document-file-types)

An alternative to control size limit would be to use .htaccess or php.ini:

For upload limit you can set in .htaccess one of the following;

```
LimitRequestBody 1073741824  //( 1MB)
php_value upload_max_filesize 1M
php_value post_max_size 1M
```

For php.ini you can set `upload_max_filesize = 1M`

Comment: You're missing the following line at the end of `restrict_mime` function: `return $mimes;`