# Limit upload file type on one custom post type

Tags: uploads, filters

Is there any way to limit the filetypes allowed for upload based on the current post type?

For example, I have a custom post type called `documents`. I have a `File upload` custom field which calls the Media Uploader (media-upload.php) and I have the possibility to upload a file. I want to restrict the file to `pdf`, `doc` and `xls`.

However, I also have a post type called `illustrations` in which I want to limit the upload file types to `jpeg`, `png` or `gif`.

I am currently trying Mike Schinkel's answer from [Limit image upload to one and disable audio, video and other document file types to upload](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/8111/17305) to restrict the file types, but I don't know how to vary the array of permitted filetypes based on the current post type.

```
 if ('image'!=$category || !in_array($type,array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'))) {
    $file['error'] = "Sorry, you can only upload a .GIF, a .JPG, or a .PNG image file.";
}
```

I tried using `get_current_screen()` but it returns the id of the media uploader itself. I also tried using `global $post` but I didn't get anything.

Or would it be simpler to [add a filter to `upload_mimes`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/18114/17305) based on the current post type?

Any suggestions?

**Answer:**

```
if( isset( $_REQUEST['post_id'] ) && $post_type = get_post_type( absint( $_REQUEST['post_id'] ) ) ) {

    if( 'illustrations' === $post_type ){
     $filetype = array('png', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'jpg');
     $message = 'Only PNG, JPEG, JPG, and GIF allowed.';
    }

     elseif( 'documents' === $post_type ){
      $filetype = array('doc','docx','pdf','xls', 'xlsx', 'zip');
      $message = 'Only PDF, DOC, DOCX, XLS, XLSX, and ZIP allowed. ';
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure `$_REQUEST['post_id']` will hold the post ID you're attaching uploads to. So something like this perhaps:

```
if ( isset( $_REQUEST['post_id'] ) && $post_id = absint( $_REQUEST['post_id'] ) ) {
    switch ( get_post_type( $post_id ) ) {
        case 'document' :
            if ( ! in_array( $type, array( 'pdf', 'msword', 'vnd.ms-excel' ) ) )
                $file['error'] = '...';
            break;

        case 'illustration' :
            // and so forth
    }
}
```