# Limit image upload to 10

Tags: uploads

Based on [this previous WPSE question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8107/limit-image-upload-to-one-and-disable-audio-video-and-other-document-file-types):

I tried a limit of 10 files, but it did not work:

```
if ( count( get_posts( "post_type=attachment&post_parent={$post_id}" ) ) > 10 )
```

How to limit it to 10 images?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

here you go:

```
get_posts(array('post_type'=>'attachment', 'numberposts' => 10, 'post_parent' => $post_id));
```

this will return you upto 10 posts.

Comment: if you want to get only published files, you should use 'post_status' => 'published' too.

Comment: I want to limit to only upload 10 images per post...