# Image limit from 1 to 5

Tags: php, images, limit

I found this code posted by: MikeSchinkel some time ago have a question how to change this code that i will be able to upload max 5 pictures insteed of 1 ? :)

```
    add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'yoursite_wp_handle_upload_prefilter');
function yoursite_wp_handle_upload_prefilter($file) {
  // This bit is for the flash uploader
  if ($file['type']=='application/octet-stream' && isset($file['tmp_name'])) {
    $file_size = getimagesize($file['tmp_name']);
    if (isset($file_size['error']) && $file_size['error']!=0) {
      $file['error'] = "Unexpected Error: {$file_size['error']}";
      return $file;
    } else {
      $file['type'] = $file_size['mime'];
    }
  }
  list($category,$type) = explode('/',$file['type']);
  if ('image'!=$category || !in_array($type,array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'))) {
    $file['error'] = "Sorry, you can only upload a .GIF, a .JPG, or a .PNG image file.";
  } else if ($post_id = (isset($_REQUEST['post_id']) ? $_REQUEST['post_id'] : false)) {
    if (count(get_posts("post_type=attachment&post_parent={$post_id}"))>0)
      $file['error'] = "Sorry, you cannot upload more than one (1) image.";
  }
  return $file;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. Please look into [ask]. This is no WordPress question, just a PHP one and will be better asked on SO.

Comment: You might get a little more help if you also link to where you found the code you posted, to add some context.

Comment: You're better off adding a comment to the original question asking for that option; this appears to be it:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8107/limit-image-upload-to-one-and-disable-audio-video-and-other-document-file-types

Comment: tnorthcutt Hey i have found it in here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8107/limit-image-upload-to-one-and-disable-audio-video-and-other-document-file-types

songdogtech yes but it says You must have 50 reputation to comment

Comment: Anyone  ? Maybe someone know some plugin that allow only upload images and some amount of them pre user ?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but I believe you would simply change some of the code close to the end of the snippet you posted.

```
if (count(get_posts("post_type=attachment&post_parent={$post_id}"))>5)
  $file['error'] = "Sorry, you cannot upload more than five (5) images.";
```

Let me know if this doesn't address your needs.

Comment: Sorry the code not working. You can upload more than 5 images. Wow i can post now...

Comment: Well, given your email I tried to help with the limited time I have today. Sorry this didn't do it.

Comment: Ok no problem can You try again please :) If You have a bit of free time .